# Explain verse 39:6

Tags: quran

First Adam was created, then his wife and then people. But why is it said in 39:6 that Allah first created people from one person (Adam) and only then created a woman from Adam?

> He created you from one soul. Then He made from it its mate, and He
> produced for you from the grazing livestock eight mates. He creates
> you in the wombs of your mothers, creation after creation, within
> three darknesses. That is Allah, your Lord; to Him belongs dominion.
> There is no deity except Him, so how are you averted? (Az-Zumar [39] :
> 6)

I'm just confused by the word "Then" (summa) here.

Comment: You already say "First Adam was created, *then* his wife." So, I don't understand why you would be confused if Allah used "then" as well.

Comment: Read the Quran more carefully. At the beginning of the verse it is written "He created you from one soul." The keyword is "created you".

Comment: @Z. Not Adam, but you (people).

Comment: The verse is crystal clear Allah created Adam first, **then** his wife (from -a part of- Adam) and then their offspring in the manner we still observe today and therefore he created all of us from Adam.

Answer (score 1):

This is a reference to what the Prophet (SAW) said in a hadith:

> When Allah created Adam He wiped his back and every person that He created among his offspring until the Day of Resurrection fell out of his back. [...] ([Sunan Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3076))

Allah also refers to this incident in another verse:

> And [mention] when your Lord took from the children of Adam - from their loins - their descendants and made them testify of themselves, [saying to them], "Am I not your Lord?" They said, "Yes, we have testified." [This] - lest you should say on the day of Resurrection, "Indeed, we were of this unaware." (7:172)

So, Allah created the offspring of Adam (AS) right after He created him. Then, after this was over, Allah created Hawwa (AS).

Another interpretation people gave is that this is a case of abbreviation, and the verse means:

> He created you from [the making of] one soul. Then He made from it its mate

Or something similar to that.

Another interpretation people gave is that the ثُمَّ does not indicate time in this verse, but it has the same meaning as "and" or "furthermore". Like in verses 75:34-35.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

The verse before puts it in the context of creation. "You" is Adam.
Adam is not only a proper name, it means "man" and "mankind". In contrast to Noah and all following prophets, Adam is an allegorical person. The mate is Eve who is also an allegorical person.

The passages cited in the answer of TheZ also explain well if we read "you" as well as "Adam" in the sense of "mankind"

The importance of the Surah is that we should be grateful to God because He is all and He is our only support because nothing is without Him.